# My ElasticSearch Query in .net is way to slow, Any Suggestions?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, search

```
var response = _client.Search<ModelName>(s => s
                                   .Index("products")
                                   .Query(q => q
                                   .MultiMatch(m => m
                                    .Fields(fields => fields
                                        .Field(p=>p.ManufacturerPartNumber,1)
                                        .Field(p => p.Name,5)
                                        .Field(p => p.FullDescription,1.2)
                                        .Field(p => p.ShortDescription,1.2)
                                        .Field(p => p.Sku,1))
                                            .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                                            .Operator()
                                            .Query(term))));

var datasend = (from hits in response.select hits.Source.ToList();
var productIds = datasend.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
var products = _productService.GetProductsByIds(productsIds);
```

Any suggestions to optimize my query? I have one index in kibana and 10600 products here.

Comment: 106000 products

Comment: Can you provide some statistics, what is "way to slow"?

Comment: when i search it in network it shows that it took 19s to get the response.But the  most surprising fact is  that yesterday it was way to fast it was getting data in 100ms.I don't know what should be problem with my query?

Comment: @BidzinaGoginashvili can you provide the elasticsearch JSON of your query and directly run it against elasticsearch, where in response elasticsearch shows hoe much time it took to run it.

Comment: GET /products/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {}},
  "size":10000
}

Comment: it shows that 264 in took is it ms or what it is ?

Comment: any suggestions MR Amit Khandelwai?